# Migrating the model from Client that refers a Company to Client that can refer multiple Companies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I'm thinking of allowing more flexibility in my Sales app. Up until this moment the Clients table had a company_id column essentially allowing a client to only belong to one company at a time. I want to allow the same client data to be visible in multiple companies partener list.

How would a migration to this scenario look like? I essentially have to construct another table to store this more complex relationship as rows of client_id and company_id so they can both appear multiple times.

One would need:

- Create a ClientCompanyJoinTable.
- Move current Clients table company_id column data for each Client to the join table.
- Remove the Clients table company_id column.

Answer (score -1):

You should have 2 models then, Client model and Company model.
You can use [associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

In the Client model:

```
    belongs_to :company
```

In the Company model:

```
    has_many :clients
```